# MS Access Dropdowns to filter through table

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

i have a big table, and have created a form that filters through that data.
However, at the moment, these filters do not work.
There are dropdown filters which correspond to columns and the idea is to choose a value from a specific column and get the rows with only the choosen value, also to filter few columns at once like that if neccessary - each box has mostly the same code, just the change of names.
Here is an example of one box code :

```
Private Sub klk_AfterUpdate()
    Dim klkxas As String
    klkxas = "Select * from daca where ([wdwqd] = '" & Me.cboLiefName & "') and ([sdcxsadc] = '" & Me.cboSRat & "') and ([Verantwortlicher] = '" & Me.cboVerant & "') and ([cxsacx] = '" & Me.cboLiefKat & "') and ([qxqxsa] = '" & Me.cboliefart & "') and ([sxsa] = '" & Me.cboLand & "') and ([sdxs] = '" & Me.cboAudErg & "')"
    Me.Form.RecordSource = klkxas
    Me.Form.Requery
    
End Sub
```

Can someone help me on how to change the code so it works?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain *does not work* which is not helpful to us. Do you receive an error? Do you receive undesired results like form filters out everything when comboboxes are changed?

Answer (score 1):

If I were to guess, your issue is that even selecting one or more but not *all* comboboxes (i.e., leaving some comboboxes blank) results in no returned rows. Per your attempted query, this is not an error but valid result of SQL logic. Your users would need to correctly select values in all seven comboboxes to get any rows back.

One solution of this dynamic filtering problem is to use `NZ` (or `IIF`) to match each field to itself for non-selected comboboxes. Also, use a saved SQL query that points to form controls without any concatenation of VBA values and punctuation of quotes.

Below will return values if *any* one or *all* controls are selected. But do note after combobox selection, only rows with non-`NULL` across all fields will be returned. Be sure to adjust `myForm` to actual form name in query:

**SQL** *(save as separate query and as recordsource to form)*

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Lieferant
WHERE [Bezeichner] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboLiefName, [Bezeichner])
  AND [S_Rating] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboSRat, [S_Rating]) 
  AND [Verantwortlicher] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboVerant, [Verantwortlicher])
  AND [Lieferantenkategorie] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboLiefKat, [Lieferantenkategorie])
  AND [Lieferantenart] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboliefart, [Lieferantenart])
  AND [Land] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboLand, [Land])
  AND [Audit_Ergebnis] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboAudErg, [Audit_Ergebnis])
```

**VBA** *(single line!)*

```vb
Private Sub cboSRat_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Form.Requery    
End Sub
```

---

If needing to capture rows with potential `NULL`s, integrate `OR` conditions:

**SQL**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Lieferant
WHERE ([Bezeichner] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboLiefName, [Bezeichner])
       OR (Forms!myForm!cboLiefName IS NULL AND [Bezeichner] IS NULL)
      )
  AND ([S_Rating] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboSRat, [S_Rating]) 
       OR (Forms!myForm!cboSRat IS NULL AND [S_Rating] IS NULL)
      )
  AND ([Verantwortlicher] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboVerant, [Verantwortlicher])
       OR (Forms!myForm!cboVerant IS NULL AND [Verantwortlicher] IS NULL)
      )
  AND ([Lieferantenkategorie] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboLiefKat, [Lieferantenkategorie])
       OR (Forms!myForm!cboLiefKat IS NULL AND [Lieferantenkategorie]IS NULL)
      )
  AND ([Lieferantenart] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboliefart, [Lieferantenart])
       OR (Forms!myForm!cboliefart IS NULL AND [Lieferantenart] IS NULL)
      )
  AND ([Land] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboLand, [Land])
       OR (Forms!myForm!cboLand IS NULL AND [Land] IS NULL)
      )
  AND ([Audit_Ergebnis] = NZ(Forms!myForm!cboAudErg, [Audit_Ergebnis])
       OR (Forms!myForm!cboAudErg AND [Audit_Ergebnis] IS NULL)
      )
```

Comment: Where to save this sql query? And where to add recordsource?

Comment: Save the query in the database like any other Access object (tables, forms, reports, macros, modules). Specifically, in Query Design, place this query in *SQL View* and save. Then, in Form Design assign this named query to the form's Recordsource property.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you (your code) must expand the *where* clause, for example:

```
myLieferantName = "Select * from Lieferant where [Bezeichner] = '" & Me.cboLiefName & "' And [Land] = '" & Me.cboLand & "'"
```

As a side note, a requery isn't needed after adjusting the recordsource:

```
Me.RecordSource = myLieferantName
' Me.Form.Requery
```

Comment: But if i put AND, then all dropdowns must be updated? And also, should i then put in each snippet of a code like in the above code inside of a SELECT query ALL dropdowns ?

Comment: The generic method is to build and concatenate the _where_ clause to only include those comboxes not having a value of _Null_. Create a function to do that, and call it from the `AfterUpdate` event of every combobox.

Comment: How to create such function? I am new to vba, that is why i am asking.

Comment: Here is one approach: [Building a Dynamic Where Clause](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3837751/Building-a-Dynamic-Where-Clause.htm).

Comment: Hey, i edited my question and code, since it still does not work, can you give an advice?

Comment: Don't know what "does not work" means, but with this _fixed_ code all comboboxes must be selected and all fields must be _text_ as you have wrapped all values in quotes.